# What about 1 Samuel ch. 16?

Tags: king-david, samuel-shmuel-book-of, king-saul, hermeneutics

In 1 Samuel ch. 16:14-23 there's a strange story about an "evil spirit from the LORD" who started to terrify Shaul Ha-Melech until the young David was called to present before the king & play the lyre for him.
Just after David played the lyre, "Saul would find relief and feel better, and the evil spirit would leave him".
The story is even more strange due to the fact that Shaul Ha-Melech killed himself (1 Sam 31:4), even though this voluntary death was not due to depression, the two episodes seems to have something in common, the Freudian Thanatos instinct.
What do you think about it?

Comment: It wasn't quite a voluntary death. He just killed himself before the enemy got to him.